# jQuery find - can I use a callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to figure out if I can call a function inside of find() as below but I'm not getting anything returned to the console. Is this possible with find() or do I need to find an alternative?

```
$(".tdInner1").find(".block", function () {
    if( $(this).next().hasClass("continuation") ) {
        console.log("yes");
    } else {
        console.log("no");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

```
$(".tdInner1").find(".block").each(function () {
    if( $(this).next().hasClass("continuation") ) {
        console.log("yes");
    } else {
        console.log("no");
    }
});
```

Or maybe [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$(".tdInner1").find(".block").filter(function () {
    return $(this).next().hasClass("continuation");
});
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks much - returning what I need now.

Comment: `$(".tdInner1").find(".block")` is the same as `$(".block", ".tdInner1")` or even `$(".tdInner1 .block")`.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame it is not the same, it is better.

Answer (score 3):

You need `jQuery` `each()`.

```
$(".tdInner1").find(".block").each( function () {
    if( $(this).next().hasClass("continuation") ) {
        console.log("yes");
    } else {
        console.log("no");
    }
});
```

You can read more about `jQuery` `each()` in [Official Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

or you can use `filter()`

```
var block = $(".tdInner1 .block");

var continuation_is_next = block.next().filter(".continuation").prev();
```

or like this

```
var continuation_is_next=  $(".tdInner1 .block + .continuation").prev();
```